# How to change execution order of two threads on the basis of odd or even number in C?

Tags: c, multithreading, semaphore

I have two threads `thread1`,`thread2` with routines `func1`,`func2` respectively . Now, on the basis of a variable `cnt` i want to change the execution order of these two threads. That is, if `cnt` is even then execute `func1` then `func2` else if `cnt` is odd then execute `func2` then `func1`.I have to do it when `cnt` is from 1 to 100.

I have to achieve through the use of semaphores only. I have attempted to solve it using following code. But the code is not good enough.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<semaphore.h>

int cnt=1;
sem_t e_lock,o_lock;

void* func1()
{
  while(cnt<=100)
   {
    if(cnt%2==0)        //if even exec then p1
    {
        printf("value of count: %d\n",cnt);
        sem_wait(&e_lock);
        printf("even execution, process 1 first\n");
    }else 
    {
        sem_post(&o_lock);
        printf("odd execution, process 1 second\n");
        cnt++;
    }
  }
}

void* func2()
{
  while(cnt<=100)
  {
    if(cnt%2!=0)        //if odd exec then p1
    {
        printf("value of count: %d\n",cnt);
        sem_wait(&o_lock);
        printf("odd execution, process 2 first\n");
    }else 
    {
        sem_post(&e_lock);
        printf("even execution, process 2 second\n");
        cnt++;
    }
  }
}
 void main()
  {

     pthread_t thread1,thread2;

     pthread_create(&thread1,NULL,func1,NULL);
     pthread_create(&thread2,NULL,func2,NULL);

     pthread_join(thread1,NULL);
     pthread_join(thread2,NULL);
  }
```

Please explain the changes.

Comment: I think you're over-thinking it, and not letting `main()` do its part. At least I would just block each thread and let `main()` do the signalling.

Comment: There is no reason to use threads this way. If you need to do things sequentially, don't use threads.

Comment: Its right that i need not use threads if sequential execution  is needed. But that's the challenge.

Comment: Start by initialising the semaphores.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to declare the shared variable `cnt` as `volatile`:

```
volatile int cnt=1;
```

Without `volatile`, the compiler was allowed to generate code where the variable value is held in a register, and changes by the other thread might not be seen.